# How to avoid warning from nested deprecated function call?

Tags: c++, c++14, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I support a C++ library, and want to declare a number of legacy functions as deprecated. Unfortunately, these functions call one another, and I receive warnings from their compilation. For example:

```
[[deprecated]] void foo();
[[deprecated]] void bar() { foo(); }
```

I would like to avoid a warning about calling deprecated function from bar() body compilation, but still has that warning if some outside function (not marked as deprecated) calls foo() or bar(). Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Maybe extract `foo()` body to `fooImpl()`, which will not be deprecated?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but will require significant work if there a number of such functions.

Comment: You could slap a `#pragma warning disable` (or the equivalent of your compiler) around those functions. If they are somewhat grouped together it shouldn't be too complicated. If your function definition is in a separate source file you could disable the warning for the entire file I guess.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think that might make the situation worse. I'm pretty sure that it's the implementation that's deprecated, not the wrapper.

Comment: @TimRandall IMO, there is no much reason to mark implementation as deprecated. The main point of deprecating something to tell the user of an *interface* that they should stop using this interface. The implementation that backs up deprecated interface may or may not be useful without that interface, this is up to decision of whoever will delete this interface in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this does not work for OP's circumstance as posted, on account of `bar()` invoking `foo()` from within the library's header, there is a straightforward solution that is applicable to anyone facing the same issue without that specific constraint. So it could be useful to other people landing here.

*Effectively*, you want two different sets of headers. One when users of the library use it, and one when the library itself uses it. We can do this in this case because `[[deprecated]]` is not supposed to have any influence on the resulting generated code.

You "could" just maintain both of them separately, but that would obviously be very fragile. Thankfully, the language does provide us with a way to have two "versions" of the same header in one single file: The oft-maligned, and to be fair also oft-misused, Macro.

As a bonus, if `[[deprecated]]` happens to be what forces users to use C++14 or above, you can provide support for older versions of the standard at the same time by checking `__cplusplus` or the appropriate feature macro.

```
//mylib.h

#if !defined(MY_LIB_NO_DEPRECATE) && __has_cpp_attribute(deprecated)
  #define MY_LIB_DEPRECATED [[deprecated]]
#else
  #define MY_LIB_DEPRECATED
#endif

// ...

MY_LIB_DEPRECATED void foo();
MY_LIB_DEPRECATED void bar();

// ...

#undef MY_LIB_DEPRECATED
```

Compile the library with `-DMY_LIB_NO_DEPRECATE`, and it's like the deprecation warnings are not there for that specific phase of the process. Users will still get all the deprecation warnings, unless they explicitly opt out of them by also defining `MY_LIB_NO_DEPRECATE`.

Don't get spooked by the use of macros here. Using them to distinguish between internal/external versions of the same header is a common and well established practice. Windows dlls would be practically impossible to write without it.

In OP's case, if moving `bar()`'s definition from the header into the library's implementation is a possibility, then they should be good to go as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can ignore the deprecation warnings. It's not technically portable, but [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/98q77r1qz) on all 4 major compilers, at least:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)

#define MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_BEGIN \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wdeprecated-declarations\"")

#define MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_END \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")

#elif defined(_MSC_VER)

#define MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_BEGIN \
    _Pragma("warning(push)") \
    _Pragma("warning(disable : 4996)")

#define MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_END \
    _Pragma("warning(pop)")

#else

#define MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_BEGIN
#define MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_END

#endif
```

#### You can do it library-wide:

```
MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_BEGIN

[[deprecated]] void foo();
[[deprecated]] void bar() { foo(); }

MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_END
```

#### Or you can guard just the offending calls:

```
[[deprecated]] void foo();

[[deprecated]] void bar()
{
MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_BEGIN
    foo();
MY_LIB_IGNORE_DEPRECATED_END
}
```